etiquette when it comes to providing credit for useful posts on TeX.SE, if they show up a lot in your work
this is my first question on the Meta, so I apologize if it may not be entirely relevant.
Suppose you are a LaTeX Editor working for/under someone, and in your role as a LaTeX Editor - in addition to normal typesetting - you are also responsible for typesetting drawn diagrams using software such as TikZ.
Now suppose that a significant portion of your skills with TikZ came from studying questions and answers on this TeX.SE, and that you utilize certain skills which were taught to you by others.
My question is this: what is the etiquette when it comes to providing credit for useful posts on TeX.SE, if they show up a lot in your work? Like, what if you publish a paper, or a book which involves a lot of TikZ?
For instance, let's say that I use a concept which I needed to consult a TeX.SE post for. Should I cite that in my final work?
What if I learned a concept previously and forgot the post I learned it from? Would it still be bat etiquette to not provide credit for that post, even though I forgot?
Are there any points which I may have overlooked that you think would be valuable for me to know?
Thank you

As an update, I would mention that I like to make animations using TikZ. In doing this, I rely heavily on the TeX.SE community for technical questions when I run into roadblocks. I currently share these animations as my work when trying to obtain typesetting opportunities. Should I be documenting useful posts in my Python scripts which make them? Obviously I can't document citations in the GIFs themselves. I would just feel bad if I'm not affording due credit, and wanted to ask.
What if I made money using a TeX.SE post's response to fix a small part of my work? Is it ethical for me to be rewarded, even when I am doing the substantial portion of the work, if a part of my work required me to use someone else's answer? Do I owe them anything?

Edit 2:
It was brought to my attention that a similar question was asked before this: What's our "required attribution"?
While Andrew's question is very well conceived and highlights the issue, it more so is asking about what is "required" and  not necessarily what is considered "polite." In asking this question, my goal was not only to do it "properly," but also in a way that would not offend relevant community members.
Also, while Andrew wrote a very good question, I found that all of the responses didn't go into a level of depth that I'd have liked to see - with no offense to the authors intended, of course.
Max's answer to my question provided much more clarity than these - again, imho and with no offense intended towards the authors.

This question is similar to: What's our "required attribution"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you for your comment @Marijn. My searches did not identify that question because I used different terminology I think this question elaborates on Andrew's a bit, going from what is "required" to what is also considered "polite." That being said, I can see the overlap. Max's answer also - imho - went into a greater level of clarity than the answers in your link. I'm not sure how to edit the question to emphasize these slight but meaningful - at least to me - differences. Feel free to close if you disagree.

I expecially found https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/676/ relevant, I have seen this type of acknowledgement various times in published works, and I think it is a nice/polite way of giving credit.

Regarding closing this meta question or keeping it open I'm fine with it either way, the questions are now already linked by my comment so I future visitors can find one of them through the other.

Do you give credit in your figures to Till Tantau for creating TikZ? What about Leslie Lamport for creating LaTeX, Donald Knuth for creating TeX, or all the authors for the dozens of packages that you (probably) use?
The TeX.SE answerers contribute lots to the TeX community both in coding and in documentation, but the authors above have arguably contributed much more. (To be fair though, there's fairly substantial overlap between TeX.SE users and package authors)
So now the question is, should you credit all these people? Well, I'm sure that the authors would all appreciate it, but I wouldn't quite call it necessary. What is necessary is that you comply with the licences for the answers and packages, but this generally* doesn't place any requirements on a compiled PDF.
At the end of books, there is sometimes a “colophon” section where authors describe how they typeset the book. But this is usually limited to crediting LaTeX as a whole plus the fonts used, although it sometimes mentions the engine, document class, and a few major packages (like microtype and TikZ). I've also sometimes seen thanking the entire TeX.SE community, but I don't think that I've ever seen a complete listing of packages and answers used (although I'm sure that someone has done it before).
Anyways, this is a long-winded way of saying that it's polite to cite any answers (and packages) that you use, but there's no implicit community expectation for you to do so. If you copy an entire figure directly from an answer, I'd personally cite it, but I otherwise wouldn't worry too much about it.

*The most common licences for answers and packages are respectively CC-BY-SA and LPPL. These two licences mostly just require that you provide authorship and licence information in any code that you directly copy and distribute. As long as you're only distributing the output of compiling said code, you generally shouldn't need to do anything. Of course, read the full licence terms for a complete list of requirements.

Thank you for your detailed response. I appreciate the rhetorical feedback about citing Till Tantau for creating TikZ figures. I will speak with people I may work for about the colophon approach.

You quote or paraphrase or summarize when you present findings that you did not gain yourself, but that you received from others. Both quoting and paraphrasing and summarizing require citing finders of those findings or at least those who conveyed those findings to you. Because it is not appropriate to claim scientific/academic recognition for a process of gaining findings that you did not develop and/or not carry out yourself, but that was developed and/or carried out by someone else.
When you use a tool—e.g., a font, a LaTeX package, a comfortable desk chair, good reading glasses, an environment where you can focus on your work, a computer, ...—that someone else makes available to you while that usage serves the purpose of making it easier for you to present findings of yours, then that does not automatically mean that you present findings of those who provide those tools or claim scientific/academic recognition for the findings of those who provide those tools.
In this sense, it is not always necessary to cite these people. But it is commendable to be grateful to them for their work and for making it available to you. This gratitude can be expressed in various places in the paper. For example in paratext like preface or footnotes or colophon.
If you use an image/an illustration that someone else created for presenting findings of others, this can be considered a quotation in image form, so the source of the illustration and the sources of the findings presented by means of the illustration are to be acknowledged/cited.
(Hereby "usage" is not restricted to presenting an exact copy of the illustration. Usage can as well be presenting a variant of the illustration where modifications were done by you as if you quoted a piece of text and added your own remarks and/or emphasizing.)
If, as a means of presenting your own findings, you create your own illustration, applying methods and/or means that others taught and/or otherwise made available to you, then you are not claiming scientific/academic credit for their findings.
It is commendable to be grateful for having been shown these methods/for these means having been made available to you. However, expressions of such gratitude are not quotations or citations but paratext.

Since I do make significant use of this community for my own professional development, I will approach people I work for about providing credit to the community for the methods I employ (especially with TikZ, for which this community is indispensable). I think I will also try to add a note in scripts which generate my GIFs, thanking you all collectively, maybe with special recognition for super-valuable posts. For books, I really like the idea of a colophon, and the answer that Marijn mentioned: tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/676
